# prototype : update tbody content dynamically

Tags: prototypejs, prototype

I have below HTML, i am trying to update the content of tbody dynamically using ajax. I have response html all i want is to update the tbody content using prototype. Till now i have tried `$('table-body').innerHTML="html content here";`

```
<tbody class="table-body">
    <tr>
        <td id="11" class="consumables model" width="15%">Aficion SP 20022</td>
        <td id="12" class="consumables type" width="15%">Print Cartridge</td>
        <td class="consumables" width="15%">Black </td>
        <td class="consumables" width="15%">15000 </td>
        <td class="consumables" width="15%">
        <td class="consumables" width="25%">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="10" class="consumables model" width="15%">Aficion SP 2002</td>
        <td id="12" class="consumables type" width="15%">Print Cartridge</td>
        <td class="consumables" width="15%">Black </td>
        <td class="consumables" width="15%">15000 </td>
        <td class="consumables" width="15%">
        <td class="consumables" width="25%">
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="2" class="consumables model" width="15%">Aficion SP C242SF</td>
        <td id="14" class="consumables type" width="15%">Print cartridge SP 4100</td>
        <td class="consumables" width="15%">Magenta </td>
        <td class="consumables" width="15%">50000 </td>
        <td class="consumables" width="15%">
        <td class="consumables" width="25%">
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to solve this

1. change the class to an id on the `<tbody>` tag and then do `$('table-body').update("html content here")`
2. use the class to select the first element matching that selector `$$('.table-body').first().update("html content here")`

Comment: even this had worked $('table-body').innerHTML="html content here";